# MySQL , Apply Configuration , Starting Server

Tags: mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4QFl.jpg)I am new to dev area , I am trying to install and configure MySQL Server into one of my older dev box (Windows 2008 R2 | 64Bit | 4GB Ram) .. 
I really dont know where am I making the mistake , can some one help .. Attached the screenshot .
enter image description here

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lS6k7.jpg)

Comment: There are 2 screenshots here .. if you are not able to view , Please reply so that I can try adding again

Comment: Alright , Admin can delete this post , I found the issue ...